# Error in Machine Learning Code - Image Dataset Training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am currently working on a machine learning project that involves training a convolutional neural network (CNN) on an image dataset. I am using Python and a popular deep learning library to build and train the CNN. However, I am encountering an error during the training process, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense

# Load the image dataset (example: Cats vs. Dogs)
# Assuming the dataset is organized with 'train' and 'test' directories
# And each directory contains 'cat' and 'dog' subdirectories with corresponding images
train_data_dir = 'path_to_train_directory'
test_data_dir = 'path_to_test_directory'
image_size = (150, 150)
batch_size = 32

# Data augmentation and preprocessing for training set
train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'
)

# Build the CNN architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10)  # Error occurs in this line
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, 150, 150, 3, 32)
```

Comment: This is strange. I ran your code and did not get the error. It also looks fine to me. Did you set the path to your data correctly? What do you get when you insert `print(len(next(iter(train_generator))))` `print(next(iter(train_generator))[0].shape)`
`print(next(iter(train_generator))[1].shape)` right after creating the `train_generator`?

Answer (score 0):

I could not replicate your error, just want to point out that `ImageDataGenerator` is deprecated. I rewrote your code with the new functions:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense

# Load the image dataset (example: Cats vs. Dogs)
# Assuming the dataset is organized with 'train' and 'test' directories
# And each directory contains 'cat' and 'dog' subdirectories with corresponding images
train_data_dir = 'path_to_test_directory'
test_data_dir = 'path_to_test_directory'
image_size = (150, 150)
batch_size = 32

train_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_data_dir, label_mode='binary', batch_size=batch_size, image_size=image_size)
# you could do some optimization with train_dataset.cache() or .prefetch here
# Rescaling could also be done before training with train_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (x/255., y))
data_augment = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip('horizontal')
])

# Build the CNN architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(data_augment)
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10)  # Error occurs in this line
```

I moved the data augmentation to layers and inserted them at the start of the network. Note that there is no augmentation layer for shear, it seems it moved to tensorflow_addons, but they stopped active development, so.. yeah.

This goes a bit off-topic, but I had problems with corrupted images when working with the cat vs dog dataset. To find them one could run this script:

```
bad_apples = []
for dir_ in os.scandir('/directory-to-folder/PetImages'):
    for image in os.scandir(dir_.path):
        im = cv2.imread(image.path)
        if im is None:
            bad_apples.append(image.path)
            # os.remove(image.path)  # uncomment to remove the file instead
print(bad_apples)
```

I still get some errors when loading the images with TensorFlow, but not with openCV. I'll come back to this answer later, but maybe it helps you already.